# Lots of horizontal lines in mplfinance

Tags: python, mplfinance

I ask for help, because I can not understand what is wrong.
There is a chart, you need to draw 2 horizontal lines on it, but for some reason I encounter a validator error
Code:

```
    df.set_index("Time", inplace=True)
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)

    mpf.plot(df, type='candle', style='yahoo', title="Stock Price", ylabel='Price',
             alines=dict(alines=[line_1, line_2], colors="r", linestyle="-"))
    mpf.show()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: kwarg "alines" validator returned False for value: "{'alines': [[('189', 0.06682), ('999', 0.06682)], [('191', 0.06954), ('999' , 0.06954)]], 'colors': 'r', 'linestyle': '-'}"
    'Validator' : lambda value: _alines_validator(value) },
```

The experience is not the first one already, and earlier the norms were created, the ** mplfinance ** library is used, but now for some reason it does not skip. Maybe my eyes are blurred. Please help.
Thank you in advance!
Have a nice day and clean working code everyone!

as a result, I need to get a graph like this, only yellow lines, but I can't do it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcxPS.png)

Comment: **You need to show how `line_1` and `line_2` are defined or set in your code.**  Please generally show ***all*** of your code, and also show the entire traceback from where the error message is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your "date/price" pairs ***do not contain dates***.  In place of the dates, you seem to be entering strings that represent integers.

For example, you have

```py
[
 [('189', 0.06682), ('999', 0.06682)], 
 [('191', 0.06954), ('999' , 0.06954)]
]
```

Perhaps this should be something more like:

```py
[
 [('2023-08-01', 0.06682), ('2023-09-01', 0.06682)], 
 [('2023-08-05', 0.06954), ('2023-09-01' , 0.06954)]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

according the doc: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance

your df must have columns named: Open, High, Low, Close

In https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb

the alines must be

```
a sequence of two or more date/price pairs, or
a sequence of sequences of two or more date/price pairs
```

while in your case, it is a dict not sequence，refer to alines (arbitrary lines) in https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb for more details.

Comment: Actually `alines` ***can*** be a dict, as long as the dict contains key `alines` which is then "a sequence of two or more date/price pairs, or a sequence of sequences of two or more date/price pairs"; as in the OP's code the dict can also contain things such as the color and/or line style.